# Implement Prometheus endpoint in an existing big system with thousand of PM counter

Tags: monitoring, endpoint, prometheus

We have an existing system (written in C++) which could generate thousands of PM counters, and the system has the complete logic of PM counter calculation. Now we want to expose this PM counters to Prometheus, how can we make it?

From my point of view, existing Prometheus client libraries can not be used, because we do not want to change the PM counter calculation logic, and implement the PM counter by this Prometheus client libraries. So my idea is to integrate a WebServer into the existing system and implement /metrics Rest interface, and return the plant text format (https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/) by this /metrics Rest interface. Do it work for us?

Thanks a lot for your comments.

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrute your attempt to solve as well as description of the problem you faced?

Comment: Thanks, coding is not started yet. I just want to get this idea review here.